# Error "Failed to get metadata of listview foo_baz for entity Account. " when trying to search list view

Tags: list-view, sosl

I am trying to use 'search in list views' SOSL [feature](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_using_listview.htm), but receiving the error mentioned in title.

The query in itself is:

> FIND {fook} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Id, Name USING LISTVIEW=foo_baz)

It's just a basic list view with couple fields, no filters. The org itself is namespaced if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

The namespace may make a difference, but it really depends on where you're calling the SOSL from. Inside of Apex or a custom namespaced API call, it probably doesn't need the namespace, but inside of the Developer Console, it probably does. It all just comes down to the defaultNamespace being used (e.g. in SOAP, the [CallOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_calloptions.htm) header).

Comment: I wanna call from Apex via Lightning cmp, but that just gives me internal salesforce error with no description so trying out in dev console. Really keen to understand how namespacing works in this case - I've tried few combos like `NameSpace.foo_baz` and `NameSpae_foo_baz`.

Comment: Ok found it. You need have double underscore after namespace, aka `NameSpace__foo_baz`