# "Invalid USING clause" error when using list view in SOSL

Tags: list-view, sosl, dynamic-sosl

I am trying to implement SOSL list view search and this is sort of [follow up question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241124/error-failed-to-get-metadata-of-listview-foo-baz-for-entity-account-when-try/241128#241128).

I am trying this query in from Apex and getting error in title:

```
System.debug(
        Search.find('FIND \'foo\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Id, Name USING LISTVIEW=MyNameScpace__foo)')
);
```

Side question - what is the difference between search.find and search.query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying this query in from Apex and getting error in title:

This query works fine in my org. I suspect you have a typo somewhere in your string. Have you tried writing this as a direct inline query? The compiler should give you more information.

> Side question - what is the difference between search.find and search.query?

The former ("find") returns a [Search.SearchResults](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Search_SearchResult.htm) object, which allows you to get [Search.SearchResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Search_SearchResult.htm) objects, which includes the "snippet" that shows you the matching text from the record. The latter ("query") returns a normal `List<List<SObject>>` and does not include the additional `WITH SNIPPET` information.